# HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth not working in Debian Lenny

Tags: bash, debian, debian-lenny

Can anyone confirm if by setting the following environmental variables under Debian Lenny, it will make previous history entries not be saved? I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release.

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
export HISTSIZE=500
```

I have added them to my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file but I keep getting repeated commands.

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://serverfault.com/questions/121396/histcontrolignoreboth-not-working-debian-lenny and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426119/histcontrolignoreboth-not-working-debian-lenny

Answer (score 2):

Use `erasedups` instead! It work for me!

```
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups
```

If you need more options separate them with:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:erasedups
```

Answer (score 1):

To uniqely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.